# Detail AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'workbook'

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I keep getting the Detail `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'workbook'`  error.

below is my code

```
import xlwt

workbook = xlwt.workbook()

sheet = workbook.add_sheet('Eswar')

sheet.write (4,4,'Test passed')

workbook.save("D:\resultsLatest.xls")
```

what have i done wrong?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: From memory: capitalize `Workbook` (with `W` not `w`)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, you are right, [docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux  Why isnt't this accepting the path I have given, it accepts only a file name when I save it using Workbook.save

Answer (score 3):

In source [code on github](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/__init__.py#L3) you can see right spelling `Workbook`. Your code should be:

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('Eswar')
sheet.write(4,4,'Test passed')
workbook.save("D:\\resultsLatest.xls")
```

Comment: Why isnt't this accepting the path I have given, it accepts only a file name when I save it using Workbook.save

Comment: Backslash is symbol with special meaning, I've updated example to fix this. It quote symbol next to it. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301068/python-backslash-quoting-in-string-literals