# xlsxwriter.Workbook AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Workbook'

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Saw this article [Detail AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'workbook'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430110/detail-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-workbook)
for the same and the error there was a typo."W" is uppercase for Workbook. Also the package used is xlwt.

I use Python 2.7 in unix. Installed XlsxWriter and used as below(Same example as given in the official page http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html)
xlsx version is 0.9.3

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()
```

I use XlsxWriter version 0.9.2.

Please help me figure out what else could be wrong here . Now i am able to get the excel output using xlwt package.

Comment: xlsxwriter version?

Comment: xlsxwriter version is 0.9.3

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your file isn't named `xlsxwriter.py`.

If it is, which was why I got the same error, all `import xlsxwriter` will do is import the current file, and not the xlsxwriter module installed in your python environment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And make sure to clean up *.pyc which will still exist after the module renaming is done.  If not, this error occurs, "ImportError: bad magic number in 'xlsxwriter': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'" since the import goes after the*.pyc file

Answer (score 1):

In `xlswriter.py` we have a module named `contenttypes.py`. There only they are importing `copy.py`.

I have a file called copy.py in the same folder. So it was throwing the same error for me. I just changed the file name.

Comment: `copy.py` is a [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) so it is probably best to avoid that as a user defined module name.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

Python is probably not finding the workbook after creating it, or it has changed its name by the time `workbook.close()` is called. Run the script from the same directory and see if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format: `(row, column, content)`

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello world') #(row, column, content) 

workbook.close()
```