# python, how to avoid read double slash from file?

Tags: python

Suppose my txt file data.txt has the following content:

```py
'\\|'
'//'
```

And I want to read the data.txt:

```
In [1]: with open('data.txt') as f:
   ...:     data = f.readlines()
   ...:     

In [2]: data
Out[2]: ["'\\\\|'\n", "'//'\n"]

In [3]: data[0]
Out[3]: "'\\\\|'\n"
```

And I want to

```
In [4]: ' '.join(data)
Out[4]: "'\\\\|' '//'"
```

But Python double read the `\`. And the expected output is:

```
In [2]: data
Out[2]: ["'\\|'\n", "'//'\n"]
```

How can I get the expected output in a more efficient and pythonic way?

Comment: Check this [Python - Backslash Quoting in String Literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301068/python-backslash-quoting-in-string-literals)

Comment: If you use an output that is meant and used for debugging purposes you will get that. Use `print` if you want to print a string.

Answer (score 3):

It did not "double read" the `\`, it simply escaped it.
The string itself is `'\\|'\n`, it is just represented as `'\\\\|'\n`.

```
for string in data:
    print(string)

>> '\\|'

   '//'
```

The blank line is the first line in the file has a trailing `\n`. You may want to get rid of that with `strip`:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = [line.strip() for line in f]
```