# Reading from file. Input character \ becomes \\ in file output. Best approach?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a Python script that is reading files as input which contains \ characters, alters some of the content, and writes it to another output file. A simplified version of this script looks like this:

```
inputFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
input = inputFile.read()
outputFile = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

outputFile.write(input.upper())
```

Given, this content in input file:

> My name\'s Bob

the output is:

> MY NAME\\'S BOB

instead of:

> MY NAME'S BOB

I suspect that this is because of the input file's format because direct string input yields desirable results (e.g. `outputFile.write(('My name\'s Bob').upper())`). This does not occur for all files (e.g. .txt files work, but .js files don't). Because I am reading different files as text files, the ideal solution should not require that input file be of certain type, so is there a better way to read files? This leads me to question whether I should use different read/write functions.

Thanks in advance for all help

Comment: I ran your program and got `MY NAME\'S BOB`. What technique do you use to view the written file? Text editors may view the backslash as a meta character and display things differently. Just do a simple "cat" or "type" of the file to see what's really in it.

Comment: I also can't replicate your problem

Comment: `print yourstring`, don't just look at what `yourstring` evaluates to at the REPL -- the latter prints the `repr()` form, which will will escape backslashes by doubling them, even though there's only *actually* a single backslash in the literal content.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301068/python-backslash-quoting-in-string-literals/301075