# Include both single quote and double quote in python string variable

Tags: python

I am trying to do an insert in postgres through python (psycopg2). I need to include both single and double quotes in the string that does the insert.
This is my code:

```
table_name = "my_table"
values_to_insert = ["""O'neal""", '''"The Film "''']
column_name_list = ["UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn"]

"INSERT INTO {} ".format(table_name) + ", ".join(['''"{}"'''.format(i) for i in 
column_name_list]) + " VALUES(" + ", ".join("""'''{}'''"""
.format(i).encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape') for i in values_to_insert)
```

I expected this:

```
'INSERT INTO my_table "UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn" VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film "''''
```

But got this:

```
'INSERT INTO my_table "UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn" VALUES(\'\'\'O\'neal\'\'\', \'\'\'"The Film "\'\'\''
```

Comment: why do you encode and decode on the same line.

Comment: unicode_escape should not be involved. Use query parameters. If your column name isn’t user-provided you shouldn’t need to escape it; if it is, *why*?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you posted two hours ago?

Comment: @Ry- not sure if I got your question. My column names are in a list variable, but in the end they need to show up in the string between double quotes, the reason why is because I need to have upper and lower characters in postgres column  names and therefore whenever I call them they need to be between double quotes.

Comment: @Valentino yes, but more elaborated.

Comment: [Quoting backslashes in string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301068/quoting-backslashes-in-python-string-literals) is closely related.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the python interpreter?  Notice how x looks vs print(x) below.

If I put your code in a script and print it out it looks fine to me.

```
>>> table_name = "my_table"
>>> values_to_insert = ["""O'neal""", '''"The Film "''']
>>> column_name_list = ["UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn"]
>>> 
>>> x = "INSERT INTO {} ".format(table_name) + ", ".join(['''"{}"'''.format(i) for i in
... column_name_list]) + " VALUES(" + ", ".join("""'''{}'''"""
... .format(i).encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape') for i in values_to_insert)
>>> x
'INSERT INTO my_table "UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn" VALUES(\'\'\'O\'neal\'\'\', \'\'\'"The Film "\'\'\''
>>> print(x)
INSERT INTO my_table "UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn" VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film "'''
>>>
```

Note also that you can just use triple `"""` instead of also using `'''`

```
s = """ this has 'single' and "double" quotes """
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. that must be a psycopg2 problem then, because when I run the cursor (ex: cursor.execute(x)) it doesn't read the string that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a lot:

```
table_name = "my_table"
values_to_insert = ["O'neal", '"The Film "']
column_name_list = ["UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn"]

print "INSERT INTO {} ".format(table_name) + ", ".join(['"{}"'.format(i) for i in column_name_list]) + " VALUES(" + ", ".join(["'''{}'''".format(i) for i in values_to_insert])
```

Outputs your desired result:

```
INSERT INTO my_table "UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn" VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film "'''
```

Comment: ...not that anyone should ever use this code in production; using string concatenation substituting values into SQL queries is prone to major security risks.