# ftplib python - returning error that login or password is incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, ftplib

I am trying to use the python library "ftplib". I am able to connect to the FTP server on my MacBook just fine, using the finder settings under "Go --> Connect to Server..."

When I use ftplib in a jupyter notebook it is returning the error message:

> error_perm: 530 Login or password incorrect!

Here is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(host='ipaddress', user='myusername', passwd='mypassword')
```

where host is the ip address of the FTP server and user is my username and passwd is the password I was given. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does your username or password contain backslashes that you're not escaping?
[Quoting backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301068/quoting-backslashes-in-python-string-literals)

Comment: The user and pass does not include backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I was not on the "user list" for the server. I was able to login through my finder on Mac but Filezilla did not let me connect through python until I was added to the server user list. Bush league by our tech department, they could use an injection of talent over there.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provide should work. I tried it on my own FTP. 
Is the username and password correct? 
You receive the error `ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login incorrect.` when the credentials are not OK.

```py
from ftplib import FTP, error_perm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ftp_host = "your_host"
    username = "your_user"
    password = "your_pwd"
    try:
        ftp = FTP(host=ftp_host, user=username, passwd=password)
    except error_perm as e:
        print("Credentials are bad!")
```

Comment: This is frustrating. My username and password is definitely correct. I used the same credentials to connect to the server through my finder (Mac). I tried the code you provided above with my host, user and pass... and it returned "Credentials are bad!" obviously.

Comment: How do you give the host?

Comment: Its an IP address. Format looks like this "xxx.xx.xx.xx" with each "x" being an integer.