# How can I replace \ in a specific string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace this: `\` in a specific string:

```
'"Noir c\'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d\'espoir'
```

But when I use `.replace('\\','')`, the result is :

```
'"Noir c\'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d\'espoir'
```

Comment: you cant use double and single quotes together, use double for the string

Comment: Is there *actually* a slash in the string, or is it a consequence of how you're printing it? If you do `print(your_string)` does it still show a slash?

Comment: So what is wrong with the output you get?

Comment: Yes I see the slash when I print it

Comment: There is no slash!?

Comment: Please include the code that defines the string, and/or the result of printing it (along with the code that prints it).  If I copy and paste your string as-is into a Python interpreter, it does not contain actual backslash characters.

Comment: Anyhow, how precisely do you print it? Using `repr()` or via the interactive commandline? In that case, escaping quotes is expected when they're in the middle of a string.

Comment: I don't want the \ in my result

Comment: I think it is very likely that (as a few others have pointed out) **there is no backslash in your actual string**.  You're just seeing backslashes because you're printing its `repr`, which adds \ characters to escape the `'` inside the string.  Note that if you print a list/dict/etc that contains a string, it will show the `repr` of the string in order to disambiguate it from the rest of the formatting.

Comment: I edited your post to improve the formatting (i.e. show code as code), but it required changing the number of backslashes, but I'm sure I got it correct since otherwise the string syntax would be invalid.

Comment: @flaxon but the string contains double quotes...

Comment: @Quxntin: Please provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: @flaxon A single-quoted string can contain literal double quotes, and vice versa. `'"This is fine."'` `"'So is this.'"`

Comment: If I run `print('"Noir c\'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d\'espoir')`, the output is `"Noir c'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d'espoir`.

Comment: @jjramsey if you want to have both in the string then the one surrounding the string need to be escaped

Answer (score 3):

There is no backslash in the string. The backslash that you see in the *representation* of the string is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) to indicate that the single quote is literal, and doesn't mark the end of the string. If you print the string, you'll see that.

```
s = '"Noir c\'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d\'espoir'
print(s)
```

Output:

```
"Noir c'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d'espoir
```

---

To further illustrate, another way to create the same string is with triple-quotes and no backslashes:

```
s = '''"Noir c'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d'espoir'''
print(s)
```

And we get the same output:

```
"Noir c'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d'espoir
```

And if we `print(repr(s))`, we'll get the same representation as the original:

```
'"Noir c\'est noir", ont-ils dit, y a donc vraiment plus d\'espoir'
```

---

Related questions:

- [Quoting backslashes in Python string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/301068/4518341)
- [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24085680/4518341)